# How can I extract sudoku data from a picture?

Tags: image-processing, react-native, ocr, sudoku

## sudoku

Hi all !
I’m currently learning Elixir lang. After spending a lot of time reading, coding on exercism.io, and on a little educational project (https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/sudoku/src)  I feel now more comfortable.

My project is solving sudoku. I can now send a request to my server like:

```
http://host/sudokus?input_str=00012030…890
```

where input_str represents the 81 number of a sudoku (0 are blank case)

So backend: done !

Now the front. I’m currently creating a react-native application and I would like to do the same as google translate real time.
I mean, I would like to put the phone in camera mode scan the sudoku like a barcode and replace the blank case with the result my back compute. Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: You can easily create a 9x9 grid with numbers inside if that is your question. As for image processing, I don't know any packages at the moment that work with RN...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is completely possible. I wanted to explain how, but I remembered that, the following tutorial provides more comprehensive detail of the process.

http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-opencv-plot/

Comment: I found it as well it is great ressources :) Thank you ! I follow the implementation and create a c++ program. Do you know if it is easy after to incude this c++ chunk of code in react native to be use both in android and iOs ?

Comment: I'm not sure, since the code utilizes openCV library. I heard  it is too tricky to install the library for android. But try to understand the method, then implementation on any framework would be a piece of cake!.